# How to build a SQL statement when any combination of user input to the table is possible?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Example: the user fills in everything but the product name.

I need to search on what is supplied, so in this case everything but `productName=`

This example could be for any combination of input.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

```
    $name = $_POST['n'];
    $cat = $_POST['c'];
    $price = $_POST['p'];

if( !($name) )
{
    $name = some character to select all?
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productCategory='$cat' and   
productName='$name' and productPrice='$price' ";
```

**EDIT**
 Solution does not have to protect from attacks. Specifically looking at the dynamic part of it.

Comment: Are you aware the code you posted, as it is, is highly insecure and wide open to attacks? If not, please take 5 minutes to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
$where_array = array();

if( isset($_POST['n']) )$where_array[] = "productName = '{$_POST['n']}'";
if( isset($_POST['c']) )$where_array[] = "productCategory '{$_POST['c']}'";
if( isset($_POST['p']) )$where_array[] = "productPrice = '{$_POST['p']}'";

    $where_stmt = implode( ' and ', $where_array  );
    if( $where_stmt )  
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE $where_stmt ";
//run query
    }
```

Comment: nice, let me give that a try.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but the variables plugged in really should be mysql_real_escape_string()'d, otherwise it's susceptible to mysql injections. I've also added quotes to wrap the variables plugged in, it won't function as you've posted.

Comment: @marabutt: the number works but I get an error in the syntax for the strings. should the {} work for strings?

Comment: can you paste var_dump( $_POST );

Comment: @Sean Johnson: the single quotes did the trick. Thank you all. Very helpful!

Comment: Again, I can't stress enough that the variables need to be escaped before being plugged into the query. Never plug user data into a query string without mysql_real_escape_string()ing it or you leave your application open to injections. Check out [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and some of its practices as an alternate, secure way of executing your MySQL.